# IllegalStateException Attempting to call unbound fn

Tags: clojure, lisp

I realize that this question has been asked before, but I couldn't find an answer for the problem I have. The below code errors out at - "(println (arr 0))". This line should however print out 4? I am new to clojure and dont understand where I am going wrong here.

I tried out (defn arr [4 3 2 1]) (arr 0) in the REPL, and that seemed to work.

```
(defn swap-arr [my-arr x y]
  (assoc my-arr x (my-arr y) y (my-arr x)))

(defn minimumSwaps [arr]
  (for [i (range (count arr))]
    (do (println (arr 0))
        (while (not= i (arr i))
          (def arr (swap-arr arr (arr i) (- 1 i)))))))

(minimumSwaps [4 3 2 1])
```

PS: The code to find min swaps is not complete yet.

Comment: I edited the swap-arr method. I am trying to swap elements in the vector, and this method works in the REPL

Comment: the `swap-arr` works but the `minimumSwaps` is really not Clojure. the `for` shouldn't be used like a loop in Java or Python and binding a var with `ref` as part of the loop is not going to work. for a basic loop look at [loop in the docs](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/loop)

Comment: I think that `(println (arr 0)) will print nil in any case, whether  there's a 0 in arr or not.

Comment: Thanks! It takes some time to get used to functional way of thinking.

Answer (score 0):

I thing I realized, is that I get the error while debugging, and that is because "range" is  a lazy seq and, the REPL didnt like it.

I changed the code to this anyway -

```
(defn minimumSwaps [org-vec]
  (loop [mut-vec org-vec, i 0, swap-count 0]
(if (< i (count org-vec))
  (let [sub-arr (subvec mut-vec i)]
    (recur (swap-arr mut-vec (mut-vec i) (apply min sub-arr))
           (+ i 1)
           (if (= (apply min sub-arr) (mut-vec i)) swap-count (+ swap-count 1))))
  swap-count)))
```